# Correct Return Values between normal and optimized builds

Tags: c, compiler-construction

In slides 137-140 of [this presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/olvemaudal/deep-c), it was mentioned that bar() and maybe even foo() was compiled as inline functions for this sample program, resulting in the printout of a being 42 in normal builds even though it should technically be garbage. Do you happen to know why is the output garbage as expected when the optimizer kicks in?

I've included the source code

```
#include <stdio.h>
void foo(void)
{
    int a;
    printf("%d\n", a);
}
void bar(void)
{
    int a = 42;
}
int main(void)
{
    bar();
    foo();
    return 0;
}
```

and the command prompt printout for reference.

```
$ cc foo.c && ./a.out
42

$ cc -O foo.c && ./a.out
1606415608
```

Comment: bar() put the var a on heap. Since var was just local it was removed from heap. After that, foo() used the same adress on heap. Therefore 42 was still there. Hopefully I did not do any major mistake but I think I'm correct.

Comment: @cen: So in reality, var a isn't placed on the stack but on the heap?

Comment: It should be on the stack. Local variables are always on stack.

Comment: @cen: That's what I thought after watching a tutorial on call stack on Youtube.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just an educated guess:

In the non-optimized case the compiler reserves a space for the a variable in bar() and initializes it to 42. Then, when foo() is called, it uses the same space for the uninitialized a and prints out 42.

When it's optimized, the initialization of a in bar() is optimized away, because it's not used. Probably, even the call to bar() is eliminated. So, as expected, foo() prints out garbage, that is whatever happens to be in that memory slot (or register) at the time.

Answer (score 1):

`a` is uninitialised in the first function, which means you can't expect it to have any particular value. So compiler behaviour is correct in both cases (that you get 42 without optimisations is just a coincidence).